# SAP UI5 oData2 Model use of read method on non-key field error

Tags: model, odata, sapui5

I am trying to read data from Employee table using SAP UI5 and oData 2 Model. I am using Read method of oData model with primary key and it is working well but when I am trying to use with non key field then it is getting error with message

> No key property 'Employee_Name' exists

.

```js
oModel.read("/Employee_Service(Employee_ID=2)", {
success: function(oData, response) {
alert("Success!");
},
error: function(response) {
alert("Error");
}
```

Here Employee_ID is primary key and this code is running well.

```
oModel.read("/Employee_Service(Employee_Name='Bob')", {
success: function(oData, response) {
alert("Success!");
},
error: function(response) {
alert("Error");
}
```

This code is getting error as said earlier.

Can you please help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Only properties which are assigned as Primary key can be accessed in this way:

```
Employee_Service(Employee_ID=2)
```

To access records with other properties you can use `$filter`query option.

> The $filter system query option allows clients to filter a collection of resources that are addressed by a request URL. The expression specified with $filter is evaluated for each resource in the collection, and only items where the expression evaluates to true are included in the response.

So your URL will be like this:

```
"/Employee_Service?$filter=Employee_Name eq 'Bob'"
```

Comment: After posting the question I also tried the same but it did not solve my issue. When service is triggering it is losing all parameter and show different as:

Comment: After posting the question I also tried the same but it did not solve my issue. When service is triggering it is losing all parameter and show different as: "/Employee_Service/$batch" and resulting enter data of the table. My UI5 version is _version: 1.1.0, and UI5 mini version is _version: 1.32.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article which helps me a lot to solve the issue. Which I was trying this should work but I do not know why it is getting error. However if any one can help me to find answer of my first approach (as above) always welcome. Here is the solution which I did.

```
var la_filters = new Array();
var lv_Filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
path: "BOWTIE_CLASS",
operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
value1: bowtieClass
});

la_filters.push(lv_Filter);

oModel.read("/Employee_Service", {
filters: la_filters,
success: function(oData, response) {
alert("Success");
},
error: function(response) {
alert("Error");

}
```

> Hint URL I found here https://scn.sap.com/thread/3781251